# Where is Windows console color list?

Tags: c, winapi, console

The only that I can find [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682013%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). I think that it is not the full list... there's not common colors in there like black and white and I've already seen a console using it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Combine the flags

```
BACKGROUND_BLUE 
BACKGROUND_GREEN
BACKGROUND_RED
```

to compose your color. You can also use BACKGROUND_INTENSITY to intensify the color. Thus, a yellow background would be composed with

```
BACKGROUND_GREEN | BACKGROUND_RED |BACKGROUND_INTENSITY
```

while a duller, tan color would be:

```
BACKGROUND_GREEN | BACKGROUND_RED
```

You can do something analogous for foreground colors with the FOREGROUND_* flags.